# Division by zero while trying to plot in Netlogo

Tags: plot, netlogo, divide-by-zero

I'm fairly new to Netlogo and I'm trying to do a plot for my model. I
want to plot the average of links with respect to turtles (count links) / (count
turtles).

When I click on setup for the model though this message appears

Division by zero.
   error while observer running /
   called by plot 'Promedio conexiones para cada agente' pen 'Prom. Conex.'
   update code
   called by __CLEAR-ALL-AND-RESET-TICKS
   called by procedure SETUP
   called by Button 'setup'

It seems during setup it counts 0 turtles even though setup creates 5 turtles initially. But it apparently trie to plot something before setup finishes. Any ideas why this is happening. I put my code on the update field and nothing
on the setup field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by Atirag to his own question is correct, but here is a bit more context from the [NetLogo transition guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html):

> In order for models from previous NetLogo versions to work in 5.0
>   without changes, when an old model is opened in 5.0, any occurrences
>   of `clear-all` (or `ca`) are automatically changed to
>   `__clear-all-and-reset-ticks`, which combines the effects of `clear-all` and `reset-ticks`. The two underscores on the name indicate that this is
>   not a normal primitive, but exists only for backwards compatibility.
>
> You should remove `__clear-all-and-reset-ticks` from your code, replace
>   it with `clear-all`, and put `reset-ticks` at the end of your setup
>   procedure.

The bottom line is that the "`reset-ticks`" part of `__clear-all-and-reset-ticks` actually tries to update the plots (just like the proper [`reset-ticks`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-ticks) primitive). If you call it at the beginning of `setup`, your turtles won't be created when the plots update and something like `(count links) / (count turtles)` will, indeed, trigger a division by zero.

Side note: calling `__clear-all-and-reset-ticks` at the end of the setup procedure would not help either, since it would clear your turtles, which is not what you want. This primitive should basically never be used in NetLogo >= 5.0.

Comment: Is there really no solution?

Comment: It depends on what your problem is. In most cases, calling `reset-ticks` at the end of `setup` is the way to go. If "it doesn't help [you]", it's probably because you are doing something slightly unusual, but we can't propose a solution unless we know what it is. I'd suggest you post a separate question and link back to it here.

Comment: I had a zero in my denominator, since I was tracking a ratio on my plot. I would get an error on the first tick. I found out that I can use a constraint in the pen update command, for example: ``if count mtfs > 0 [plot (count ftms / count mtfs + 1) * 10]``. This solved my particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind got it. In the new Netlogo versions it appears you have to use CLEAR-ALL at the beginning of setup and RESET-TICKS at the end of setup instead of using __CLEAR-ALL-AND-RESET-TICKS at the beginning of setup. Otherwise plotting won't work as expected.